# Connecting to Snowflake using Okta from R Workbench

Tags: r, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Hi, I am trying to connect to snowflake from R Workbench. This is the error received while connecting with okta.**

con <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://company.snowflakecomputing.com/?authenticator=https://company.okta.com/",                 'name@company.com', 'pass')

Sep 16, 2021 10:07:42 PM net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil handleFederatedFlowError
SEVERE: IOException when authenticating with https://company.okta.com/
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /login/cert
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:611)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:508)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:457)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.isPrefixEqual(SessionUtil.java:1218)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.federatedFlowStep4(SessionUtil.java:999)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.getSamlResponseUsingOkta(SessionUtil.java:1206)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:378)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:446)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

Sep 16, 2021 10:07:43 PM net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil handleFederatedFlowError
SEVERE: IOException when authenticating with https://company.okta.com/
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /login/cert
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:611)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:508)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:457)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.isPrefixEqual(SessionUtil.java:1218)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.federatedFlowStep4(SessionUtil.java:999)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.getSamlResponseUsingOkta(SessionUtil.java:1206)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:378)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:446)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)

Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  :
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered when opening connection: no protocol: /login/cert.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that Okta is set up with MFA. If so, the error is because of that since Snowflake drivers does not support Native authentication for Okta with MFA enabled.

You need to use externalbrowser as the authenticator option if the requirement is to use Okta + MFA.

Comment: Actually we use Okta without MFA. Tried the external browser, that didn't work since this is on a server

Comment: The error message implies Okta is invoking MFA but it's strange it comes for non-MFA set up as well.From the R host, can you test by launching Snowsql and test native authentication mechanism? That will give exact information related to the issue.

Comment: Could you share example of `externabrowser` usage?